# Is Finitro Forte Plus an effective treatment for arthritis?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, nutritional-supplements

[This advertisement for a product](http://www.finitro.fr/finitro-forte-plus-10) says (French original, followed by my translation into English),

> Finitro Forte Plus montre des résultats surprenants dans le traitement de l'arthrite, de l'arthrose et d'autres problèmes d'articulation, et il est considéré comme le traitement le plus efficace dans le monde entier !
>
> ---
>
> - Conserve la souplesse des articulations.
> - Préserve la solidité des os.
> - Soulage la douleur.
> - Soutient la lubrification des articulations.
> - Aide à préserver un cartilage sain.
> - Pour la construction du nouveau cartilage.
> - L'élément de reconstruction des articulations.
>
> **Comment fonctionne Finitro Forte Plus ?**
>
> Finitro Forte Plus est le seul complément alimentaire contenant de la glucosamine, de la chondroïtine et du  Collagène de Type II  , qui est le principal composant du cartilage. Le supplément de ce Collagène de Type II d'excellente qualité permet d'inverser la détérioration du cartilage responsable de l'arthrite. Il inhibe aussi la réponse auto-immune chez les personnes souffrant de rhumatismes, ce qui permet de réduire l'inflammation des articulations. Finitro Forte Plus contient aussi du MSM et des herbes qui ont un effet anti-inflammatoire puissant et, par conséquent, la plupart des personnes qui en prennent remarquent une nette diminution de leurs douleurs articulaires en l'espace de quelques jours.  Finitro Forte Plus est le remède le plus puissant contre les douleurs articulaires.

My translation:

> ... shows surprising results in the treatment of arthritis, arthrosis, and other problems of the articulation, and is considered as the most effective treatment in the entire world!
>
> ---
>
> - Preserves the suppleness of the joints
> - Preserves the solidity of the bones
> - Relieves pain
> - Supports the lubrication of the joints
> - Helps to preserve a healthy cartilage
> - For the construction of new cartilage
>
> **How does Finitro Forte Plus work?**
>
> ... is the only dietary complement containing **glucosamine**, **chondroitin**, and **type 2 collagen**, which is the principal component of cartilage. The supplementation of this type 2 collagen permits the reversal of the deterioration of the cartilage responsible for arthritis. It also inhibits the auto-immune response with people suffering from rheumatisms, which allows to reduce the inflammation of the articulations (joints). This medicine (named "Finitro Forte") also contains **MSM** and **herbs which have a powerful anti-inflammatory effect** and, consequently, most people who take of it notice a distinct reduction of their joint pain in the space of a few days. It's the most powerful remedy against joint pain.

The ingredients are [listed on this page](http://www.finitro.fr/ingredient) and include:

> - Collagen type 2
> - Glucosamine sulphate
> - Chondroitin sulphate
> - Harpagophytum procumbens (commonly called "devil's claw")
> - Boswellia serrata (resin from the incense tree)
> - Phellodendron amurense Rupr (derived from chinese cork-oak)
> - Méthylsulfonylméthane (MSM)
> - Omega 3 fatty acids
> - Hyaluronic acid (the principal component of synovial fluid, acts as a joint lubricant)
> - DL-α-tocopherol (Vit E)
> - Urtica dioica (aka the great nettle has a purifying effects)
> - Magnesium

Now, I think that glucosamine etc. are widely sold, and I think this is a fairly typical advertisement. But I'm skeptical, because, am I right in thinking that there's no effective treatment for arthritis? Also, collegen for exampe is a type of protein, isn't it, and doesn't everyone synthesize all their protein from the essential amino acids in their diet?

So my question: is there any evidence that this product (whether you call it medicine or dietary supplement) in particular, and/or any other similar product, and/or any of the component of this product, are an effective treatment and/or have any of the beneficial effects claimed?

Comment: The current answer to [Is there evidence that glucosamine can help repair joints?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1829/2703) says that glucosamine and/or chondroitin are no better than placebo. This question isn't an exact duplicate because of other ingredients including collagen, MSM, hyaluronic acid, and "herbs which have a powerful anti-inflammatory effect".